# Create MySQL function in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I have MySQL 5.6 and I need to use MySQL 5.7 function `ST_Distance_Sphere` (for geolocalization purposes).

I found [this hack](https://www.bram.us/2018/03/01/mysql-st_distance_sphere-polyfill/) and it looks correct to me (?).

Now I'm trying to use it in Laravel 5.5.

I put it in `app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php` in `boot()` function.

I tried with `DB::statement`, `DB::raw`, `DB::unprepared`.

I tried removing `DELIMITER` and `$$`.

```
$sql = '
        DELIMITER $$

        DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `ST_Distance_Sphere`$$

        CREATE FUNCTION `ST_Distance_Sphere` (point1 POINT, point2 POINT)

            RETURNS FLOAT
            no sql deterministic
            BEGIN
                declare R INTEGER DEFAULT 6371000;
                declare `φ1` float;
                declare `φ2` float;
                declare `Δφ` float;
                declare `Δλ` float;
                declare a float;
                declare c float;
                set `φ1` = radians(y(point1));
                set `φ2` = radians(y(point2));
                set `Δφ` = radians(y(point2) - y(point1));
                set `Δλ` = radians(x(point2) - x(point1));

                set a = sin(`Δφ` / 2) * sin(`Δφ` / 2) + cos(`φ1`) * cos(`φ2`) * sin(`Δλ` / 2) * sin(`Δλ` / 2);
                set c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1-a));

                return R * c;
            END$$

        DELIMITER ;
    ';

DB::statement($sql);
```

I have a syntax error everytime. For example:

```
``Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (42000)SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 Erreur de syntaxe près de 'DELIMITER $$ DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `ST_Distance_Sphere`$$ ' à la ligne 1 (SQL: DELIMITER $$ DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `ST_Distance_Sphere`$$ CREATE FUNCTION `ST_Distance_Sphere` (point1 POINT, point2 POINT) RETURNS FLOAT no sql deterministic BEGIN declare R INTEGER DEFAULT 6371000; declare `φ1` float; declare `φ2` float; declare `Δφ` float; declare `Δλ` float; declare a float; declare c float; set `φ1` = radians(y(point1)); set `φ2` = radians(y(point2)); set `Δφ` = radians(y(point2) - y(point1)); set `Δλ` = radians(x(point2) - x(point1)); set a = sin(`Δφ` / 2) * sin(`Δφ` / 2) + cos(`φ1`) * cos(`φ2`) * sin(`Δλ` / 2) * sin(`Δλ` / 2); set c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1-a)); return R * c; END$$ DELIMITER ; )``
```

Comment: From the error message, doesn't it look like, you don't have  access to drop the function `ST_Distance_Sphere` ? Try running your SQL via MySQL Client, I am guessing you would get the same error message.

Comment: @SudiptaMondal I already tried to run this in phpmyadmin, and I didn't get any error messages.

Comment: @SudiptaMondal I think you were right, see my answer below. Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I answer my own question**

It seems I didn't have access to drop a MySQL function...

So I replaced `` DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `ST_Distance_Sphere` `` by a MySQL version check:

```
$mysql_version_check = DB::select(DB::raw('SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "version";'));
$mysql_version = $mysql_version_check[0]->Value;
if (substr($mysql_version,2, 1) < '7' AND substr($mysql_version,4, 1) < '6') {
    $sql = '
        CREATE FUNCTION `ST_Distance_Sphere` (point1 POINT, point2 POINT)

            RETURNS FLOAT
            no sql deterministic
            BEGIN
                declare R INTEGER DEFAULT 6371000;
                declare `φ1` float;
                declare `φ2` float;
                declare `Δφ` float;
                declare `Δλ` float;
                declare a float;
                declare c float;
                set `φ1` = radians(y(point1));
                set `φ2` = radians(y(point2));
                set `Δφ` = radians(y(point2) - y(point1));
                set `Δλ` = radians(x(point2) - x(point1));

                set a = sin(`Δφ` / 2) * sin(`Δφ` / 2) + cos(`φ1`) * cos(`φ2`) * sin(`Δλ` / 2) * sin(`Δλ` / 2);
                set c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1-a));

                return R * c;
            END;
    ';

    DB::unprepared($sql);

}
```

It's a bit ugly, but it appears to work...

### EDIT

Actually, it will work only the 1st time it is executed. It appears this function could save the mysql function to the mysql database. You will have an error the next times like "Mysql function already exists". You just have to comment the block above.

Comment: You need to create it in the database so that you can access it.

Comment: Thanks, actually that's what I did, even if it causes issues on export/import (function already exists).

Comment: Add a `DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS...;`