# export/import issue with mysql POINT coordinates

Tags: mysql, google-maps, phpmyadmin, coordinates, point

**I've got an issue when I export then import a MySql database from local to prod:**

*(I export and import via phpMyAdmin in "simple mode" with default options.)*

---

### Source database : Local environment MySql 5.7.19 (working)

***Table : `lieux` | InnoDB | utf8_unicode_ci***

**Column :**

- Name  => `coords`
- Type  => `point`
- Value => `'POINT(48.6863316 6.1703782)',0` (the good one)

---

### Target database : Production environment MySql 5.6.?

***Table : `lieux` | InnoDB | utf8_unicode_ci***

**Column :**

- Name  => `coords`
- Type  => `point`
- Value => `'POINT(-0.000000000029046067630853117 -3.583174595546599e227)',0` (the bad one)

---

After export/import, the point value changes and all coordinates are false.

I also have a weird display when I open .sql export in VSCode editor :

The point value looks like that : [image: capture] (the file is in UTF-8 format).

Do you know if utf-8 is problematic with coordinates points in MySql, or maybe if the older MySql version on prod server could cause this ?
Should I use utf8_mb4 charset ?

---

### EDIT : Adding more details

1. In my project (Laravel + Google Maps JavaScript API), I create (on local environment) a Place with these coordinates : `48°41'10.8"N 6°10'13.4"E`, stored in database as `POINT(48.6863316 6.1703782)` and located here :

[image: original location]

2. Then, I go in phpMyAdmin in export tab and make a simple sql export (with default options).
3. Then I log in phpMyAdmin on the prod server, go in import tab and import my sql file (also with default options).
4. When I look in the new db (on the prod server), the value is stored as `POINT(-0.000000000029046067630853117 -3.583174595546599e227)`, and is located here (after google maps corrected it by removing the excess characters) :

[image: bad coordinates]

**I went around this issue** by using Heidi SQL instead of phpMyAdmin, which is storing the values differently:

- In phpMyAdmin export .sql file : [image: capture]
- In Heidi SQL export .sql file : [image: binary thing]

---

### EDIT : Export file

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.7.4
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Hôte : 127.0.0.1:3306
-- Généré le :  jeu. 26 juil. 2018 à 03:46
-- Version du serveur :  5.7.19
-- Version de PHP :  7.1.9

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Structure de la table `lieux`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `lieux`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `lieux` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  [...],
  `coords` point DEFAULT NULL,
  [...],
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

--
-- Déchargement des données de la table `lieux`
--

INSERT INTO `lieux` (`id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, [...], `coords`, [...]) VALUES
(1, '2018-03-23 09:13:45', '2018-04-19 19:47:22', [...], '\0\0\0\0\0\0\0��I�mH@�D[@', [...]),
(2, '2018-03-23 18:11:59', '2018-07-12 16:15:06', [...], '\0\0\0\0\0\0\0���WH@.�s�w�@', [...]),
(3, '2018-04-02 14:00:29', '2018-04-19 19:47:32', [...], '\0\0\0\0\0\0\04j��E@�mWCu@', [...]);

-- --------------------------------------------------------
```

*I replaced superfluous data with `[...]`*

---

### EDIT : Trying phpMyAdmin options and command line mysqldump

I tried all relevant options in PHPMyAdmin, and nothing changed.
I also tried to export the database from the remote environment which has a different version of PHPMyAdmin => still not working.

I'm trying to export from local in command line, with this instruction:

```
C:\laragon\bin\mysql\mysql-5.7.19-winx64\bin
λ mysqldump.exe --host=localhost --user=root mydatabase > mydatabase.sql
```

But it still gives me a bad encoding :

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.7.19, for Win64 (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: db
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.7.19

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Table structure for table `lieux`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `lieux`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `lieux` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  [...],
  `coords` point DEFAULT NULL,
  [...],
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `lieux`
--

LOCK TABLES `lieux` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `lieux` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `lieux` VALUES (1,'2018-03-23 09:13:45','2018-04-19 19:47:22',[...],'\0\0\0\0\0\0\0��I\�mH@�D[@',[...]),(2,'2018-03-23 18:11:59','2018-07-12 16:15:06',[...],'\0\0\0\0\0\0\0��\�WH@.\�s�w�@',[...]),(3,'2018-04-02 14:00:29','2018-04-19 19:47:32',[...],'\0\0\0\0\0\0\04j��E@�mWCu@',[...]);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `lieux` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

*part of mysqldump command line export file*

- **How can I get more info about export process ?**
- **Do you think it could be caused by a bad value storage on row
  creation (I mean when the user create the location item)?**
- **Maybe it's linked with [this other issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50986432/create-mysql-function-in-laravel-5-5) (also mine, and only partially resolved)...**

Comment: Please provide `HEX(coords)` for each case; Spatial values are packed in some binary format.  Also, please spell out the details of export/import.

Comment: The `CHARACTER SET` should not matter.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; it will have details that you left out.

Comment: I got the export to work using HeidiSQL, where the 'point' value is written `_binary 0x000000000101000000346A1904B1A545401FA56D5743751540` instead of the weird series of symbols ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Finally, it is fixed in phpMyAdmin 4.8.6

As you can see here : https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/14588#event-2323932464

> This is now fixed by [7f454ac](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/commit/7f454ac5908e9fb6eb5c90e3a22c4da38b5266d3) and will part of the next version of phpMyAdmin (4.8.6)

Answer (score 2):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-data-formats.html

Looks like WKB format:

```
mysql> select HEX(ST_PointFromText('POINT(-0.000000000029046067630853117 -3.583174595546599e227)')); 
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| HEX(ST_PointFromText('POINT(-0.000000000029046067630853117 -3.583174595546599e227)')) |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 0000000001010000000E1BEFBFBDEFBFBDEFBFBD5748402EEF                                    |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Here are the two floating point numbers in the 'bad' one:

```
mysql> select HEX(MID(REVERSE(ST_PointFromText('POINT(-0.000000000029046067630853117 -3.583174595546599e227)')), 1, 8));
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| HEX(MID(REVERSE(ST_PointFromText('POINT(-0.000000000029046067630853117 -3.583174595546599e227)')), 1, 8)) |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| EF2E404857BDBFEF                                                                                          |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

mysql> select HEX(MID(REVERSE(ST_PointFromText('POINT(-0.000000000029046067630853117 -3.583174595546599e227)')), 9, 8));
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| HEX(MID(REVERSE(ST_PointFromText('POINT(-0.000000000029046067630853117 -3.583174595546599e227)')), 9, 8)) |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| BDBFEFBDBFEF1B0E                                                                                          |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

They seem reasonable.

It is unclear what you mean by "bad" or "false".  Please provide the SQL evidence of such.

The `CHARACTER SET` should be totally irrelevant.

Aha.  So the numbers represent latitude and longitude?  Well, `-3.583174595546599e227` (-3.58*10^227) is not a valid value.  So, work backward from that value and show all steps of generating/exporting/importing the number.  We need to discover where it got mangled.  Start by looking at the export file.

**mysqldump**

Based on your recent edit, the mysqldump is mangling `POINTs`.  I don't know the exact solution, but binary stuff needs to be done in hex (or something other than text).

- phpadmin may have a parameter??
- Maybe you can get to the mysqldump command?

**mysqldump Example**

Build test table:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE `lieux` (
    ->   `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->   `coords` point DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO lieux (coords) VALUES (ST_PointFromText('POINT(11.22 33.44)'));
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> SELECT HEX(coords) FROM lieux;
+----------------------------------------------------+
| HEX(coords)                                        |
+----------------------------------------------------+
| 000000000101000000713D0AD7A3702640B81E85EB51B84040 |
+----------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> exit 
Bye
```

and dump it:

```
~$ mysqldump  --hex-blob try lieux -u root
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.7.23, for Linux (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: try
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.6.22-71.0-log

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Table structure for table `lieux`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `lieux`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `lieux` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `coords` point DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `lieux`
--

LOCK TABLES `lieux` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `lieux` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `lieux` VALUES (4,0x000000000101000000713D0AD7A3702640B81E85EB51B84040);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `lieux` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2018-08-20 13:38:24
```

Comment: I added a part of the export file code to my question.

Comment: @CharlieWebNancy - I added something.

Comment: @CharlieWebNancy - `--hex-blob` seems to work as needed.  I don't how how to get it added to `mysqldump` in your context.  See added example.

Comment: Indeed... In any case, I can export with HeidiSQL, so... But it would be interesting to know why it works in HeidiSQL and not in phpMyAdmin

Comment: @CharlieWebNancy - Do both products use mysqldump?  Does HeidiSQL use `--hex-blob`, but phpMyAdmin not?  (That's my guess.)

Comment: I don't know where I could find this information, but yes, I guess so

Comment: I mean, I'm sure HeidiSQL is using mysqldump (according to the docs), but there is no way to get the exact command, and if it uses `--hex-blob`. But thank you for your time and your expertise !

Comment: @CharlieWebNancy - Suggest you file a bug report with phpmyadmin.

Comment: Done. For future reference: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/14588